# gensim Phrases not observing min_count parameter

Tags: python, gensim

I'm trying to train a gensim Word2Vec model with bigrams. To get the bigrams, I run the following code, with `sentences` standing for a long list of split sentences using `nltk.sent_tokenize`, lemmatized with Spacy and then lowercased:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, Phrases

bigrams = Phrases(sentences, min_count=20, threshold=10)
```

This could only include bigrams which occur >= 20 times. But when I run `bigrams.vocab`, I get:

```
defaultdict(int,
             b'inflated': 237,
             b'the_inflated': 34,
             b'inflated_bag': 1,
             b'let': 6841,
             b'bag_let': 1,
             b'let_-pron-': 3723,
             ...)
```

From what I understand, `inflated_bag` and `let_-pron-` should not be present. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or am I misinterpreting the output?

Answer (score 1):

In the gensim `Phrases` source code, `min_count` is an adjustable input to the formula for deciding which bigrams should be combined.

It *isn't* a strict cutoff (like the parameter of the same name in `Word2Vec` & related classes), below which any unigrams/bigrams are ignored or outright discarded from the survey counts.

(The doc-comments in gensim's `phrases.py` are somewhat misleading in this regard.)

Comment: Thanks, that's odd. Can I filter which bigrams are actually used by changing the `bigrams.vocab` defaultdict as a workaround?

Comment: Yes, to an extent. The decision to combine word-pairs into bigrams depends on the relative frequencies of the words individually, and the pair together – and if you delete specific entries from the `bigrams.vocab' dict, those candidate-pairs can never be combined. But note that merely having a count in that dict is a necessary but not sufficient condition for a bigram being emitted.

Comment: For example, with a `'inflated_bag':1` count, and any `min_count`>1, the `original_scorer` formula (https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/fbc7d0952f1461fb5de3f6423318ae33d87524e3/gensim/models/phrases.py#L685) will definitely report a *negative* score, which wouldn't exceed any typical `threshold` value.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, `bigrams.vocab` is just a raw count of all bigrams in the corpus but not necessarily of what's used in the model?

Comment: Yes, the `.vocab` dict of a `Phrases` instance is just raw counts – of both bigrams and unigrams – used later to calculate whether potential pairs should be combined.

Comment: Alright, if you can summarize a bit of all this in the answer I'll go ahead and accept